# WSO2 JWT claims returns wrong user

Tags: wso2, jwt, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

### Environment

Clustered API Manager 2.1.0 (two workers, one manager) and Identity Server 5.3.0 (two workers)

### Issue

When logging into a webpage, I login as the application creator. Which causes the JWT claims to be the application creator instead of user who logged in.

### Idea of issue

My idea of the problem is since the application was created by one user it uses applications client_id as authorization. Since the application is linked to the user who created the application, it logs others in as that user. So when we get the JWT claims back it has the information for the user who created the application instead of the user who logged in.

What types of things should I be looking at as a possible fix for this problem? I believe the JWT configurations can fix the problem. Which I know either api-manager.xml or identity.xml could have the answer.

How do I get the correct JWT claims back from the access token?

### JWT Sample

```
{
  "sub": "12345678",
  "http://wso2.org/claims/applicationtier": "Unlimited",
  "http://wso2.org/claims/client_id": "bzuM29gewg5gxazegXiNfkwsgz",
  "http://wso2.org/claims/keytype": "SANDBOX",
  "http://wso2.org/claims/version": "1.0.1",
  "iss": "wso2.org/products/am",
  "http://wso2.org/claims/applicationname": "CellPhones",
  "http://wso2.org/claims/enduser": "null",
  "http://wso2.org/claims/enduserTenantId": "null",
  "http://ourdomain.com/claims/client_rest_of_name": "Ben",
  "http://ourdomain.com/claims/client_surname": "Kenobi",
  "http://wso2.org/claims/subscriber": "DOMAIN/benk",
  "http://wso2.org/claims/tier": "Bronze",
  "http://ourdomain.com/claims/client_claim_source": "CLIENT_SUBSCRIBER",
  "http://ourdomain.com/claims/client_roles": [
    "Full-Time Employee",
    "Employee",
    "Technology Engineer"
  ],
  "http://wso2.org/claims/applicationid": "8",
  "http://wso2.org/claims/usertype": "APPLICATION_USER", <- Client app
  "exp": 1493232200,
  "email": "user@gmail.com",
  "http://wso2.org/claims/apicontext": "/jwt/1.0.1"
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of assumptions in your use case, it isdifficult to pinpoint.. The JWT - you mean a token passed from API to the backend? Which OAuth profile do you use to authenticate your app? (implicit, code,client credentials, password, saml)  Could not web sessions be mixed from multiple logons? (are you using cross site requests or requests to APIM are proxied?)

Comment: Did you configure the IS as the key manager? https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+the+Identity+Server+5.1.0+as+a+Key+Manager+with+API+Manager+1.10.0

Comment: 1. Yes, we have custom claims that pass enduser attributes to the backend. That attributes that end up getting passed are those of the Application Creator. I want to get the attributes of the person who logged into the application. 
2. The App is using Authorization Code. 
3. To my understanding, I'm going to say no. There are no proxies and sessions are not mixed. 
Some extra information on login, if this helps. The application links to are shibboleth/cas login page, and our users and roles are stored in LDAP.
4. Yes the identity server is the key manager.

Comment: So you wrote a custom jwt generator? Could you confirm the token used to get user claims is a user token type, not an application token? (trying to pinpoint  source of user identity)

Comment: Yes. As @GabrielVince has pointed out if it is a user access token then the claims should be the logged in users claims. If it is an application token (using client_credentials grant) then you will have details related to the application creator/

Comment: @GabrielVince I updated my question with a JWT sample. We are getting back an application token. So I'am getting back application creator details. Would using/adding a Resource Owner to the token help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with custom claims. Just had to alter code.